# How do I edit the region setting in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have signed in through Azure Portal and then created a Cloud service, Database and Storage under region "South East Asia".

Now i need to create a Mobile Service in Azure. But this is not available with region "South East Asia".

So i planned to change the region for the above services so that i can match the region available in Mobile Service.

I have tried googling it, and found answers like making a backup and then creating NewDB. but for others i am not aware how to....

Please let me know how could i accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to edit your existing Cloud Service, Database, and Storage accounts currently in 'South East Asia' so that they're in another region, for example 'East US', then you can't do that by a simple edit.  You would need to create the services and deploy the relevant code and data to the new region.